# How to update composer project containing static version numbers?

Tags: composer-php

How to update a composer project to the latest patch level when composer.json uses static version numbers like `"my/package": "1.2.34"`?

Comment: If you require a **static** version, you require exactly that version and not any other. If there was any reason to do that, did that requirement change? Why not replace the exact version numbers with a constraint that is compatible with your application?

Comment: I had to use static versions because there were some functionality breaking changes on patch level (usually should not be the case). Now I want to switch back to constraints to get the latest patch level versions and the question is if I have to „require“ all packages using this new constraint or else if there is any „update“ command to achieve this?

Comment: Editing the `composer.json`  with the new requirements and running `composer update`  should be sufficient. What have you tried sof ar? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Not stuck, just want to use it the right way. What I already did: Delete „composer.lock“, edit „composer.json“ to new constraints, run „composer install“. That worked, anything bad with this?

Comment: Yes: deleting the lock file does not make any sense. That should not be done, except when you **want** to update **all** packages